# Adding multiple jars to classpath on commandline

Tags: java, ubuntu, command-line, jar, terminal

I'm running Ubuntu and want to execute a Java file from terminal by including multiple jar files.

All my jars are included in tha jar folder.

I tried

```
javac -cp jar/A.jar: jar/B.jar: jar/C.jar: jar/D.jar MyFile.java
```

I get below error.

```
javac: invalid flag: jar/B.jar:
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible option
```

Can anyone guide how to use multiple jars in classpath ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the spaces from the classpath and add the current path

```
javac -cp jar/A.jar:jar/B.jar:jar/C.jar:jar/D.jar:. MyFile.java
```

Since Java 6 you can use classpath wilcards

```
javac -cp jar/*:. MyFile.java
```

Comment: and what about if I have to execute the classfile??

Comment: The same classpath will work for the JVM

Comment: Thanks. Works like a magic.

Comment: What if I want to include a jar and another custom class in the same directory as my Main.java file?
I tried `javac -classpath ./guava-18.0.jar:. Main.java ` but it does not find the custom class.

Comment: try `javac -classpath ./guava-18.0.jar:. *.java`

Answer (score -1):

ClassPath set through command prompt will work only for current cmd window. Once you close it and open a new cmd window it will not work. Rather than setting classpath from command prompt, keep related paths to system properties:

For windows:

go to My Computer--> Properties--> Advance System Settings--> Environment Variables--> CLASSPATH--> put your path like this--> `path1;path2;path3;.` Don't forget to keep . (DOT) at the end.

Comment: Specifying application specific jars on system level is not a way to go. This is why startup scripts exist which are often a mess, but more flexible.