Problem for implement LogBack from with Java Args
I have been stuck for some time on a problem implementing my logback
My configuration of my processing is as follows:
I use a .ksh on a Linux machine, which takes as parameters some Java libraries which are the following:
java -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -cp /appli/XXX/lib/cc_XX_XX.jar: /appli/XXX/lib/logback-classic-1.3.5.jar: /appli/XXX/lib/logback-core-1.3.5.jar: /appli/XXX/lib/ojdbc8-21.9.0.0.jar: /appli/XXX/lib/spring-aop-5.3.26.jar: /appli/XXX/ lib/spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar: /appli/XXX/lib/spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar: /appli/XXX/lib/spring-batch-test-4.3.7.jar: /appli/XXX/lib/spring-beans-5.3.26.jar: /appli/XXX/lib/spring-context-5.3.26 .jar: /appli/XXX/lib/spring-core-5.3.26.jar: /appli/XXX/lib/spring-expression-5.3.26.jar: /appli/XXX/lib/ spring-jcl-5.3.26.jar: /appli/XXX/lib/spring-jdbc-5.3.26.jar: /appli/XXX/lib/spring-oxm-5.3. 26.jar: /appli/XXX/lib/spring-retry-1.3.3.jar: /appli/XXX/lib/spring-test-5.3.26.jar: /appli/XXX/lib/spring-tx-5.3.26.jar: -Dlogback.configurationFile=/appli/XXX/conf/confLog.xml fr.xxxx.xxxx.myMainclass
When I run the java command I get the following error:
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
I transfer my logback library in the arguments, I put my xml file as input, but the implementation is not done
My logbackconfiguration.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<configuration debug="true">

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/appli/XXX/data/XXXXX/work/XXXX.txt</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>

My main class
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class mainclass{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(mainclass.class);

I tried by log4j but I have the same problem but I still get the same error
Edit :
I have implementation in my pom for Log4j
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency><groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency><groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.0</version>
    </dependency>


This question is similar to: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thx for the anwser @Joe

@Joe no, this is not a duplicate of that question. The other question uses SLF4J API without using a logger binder. But this question plainly is using one: /appli/XXX/lib/logback-classic-1.3.5.jar is in the classpath.

This is trying to use one, but it's not in the classpath at runtime, due to extraneous spaces after colons. Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155102/adding-multiple-jars-to-classpath-on-commandline, perhaps?

Thx for the anwser , I fix my problem by using Log4J instead of logback , i don't know why logback didn't work , but it work with Log4j
